# sorting object property by merge sort

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I want to sort students by their roll numbers. I know how to sort an arraylist of integers using merge sort, but sorting an ArrayList of type Student is different.

my Student class contains the following properties:

```
public static class Student
    {
        String name;
        int rollNum, WebMark, dsMark, dmMark;

        public Student(String name, int rollNum, int WebMark, int dsMark, int dmMark)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.rollNum = rollNum;
            this.WebMark = WebMark;
            this.dsMark = dsMark;
            this.dmMark = dmMark;
        }
}
```

I've seen people use Comparators  to sort ArrayLists of object's properties. However, they use it for built-in sorting like the following line (which is straightforward):

```
Collections.sort(Database.arrayList, new CustomComparator());
```

However, I want to use my mergesort functions that I wrote in my Student class.  But I still don't understand how am I going to pass the property 'rollNum' into the mergesort function and how are other properties in the ArrayList are going to be moved accordingly? I've never seen this anywhere in Google.

Here is my full code:

```
package student;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Main 
{
    public static class Student
    {
        String name;
        int rollNum, WebMark, dsMark, dmMark;

        public Student(String name, int rollNum, int WebMark, int dsMark, int dmMark)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.rollNum = rollNum;
            this.WebMark = WebMark;
            this.dsMark = dsMark;
            this.dmMark = dmMark;
        }
        public String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }
        public int getRollNum()
        {
            return rollNum;
        }
        public int getWebMark()
        {
            return WebMark;
        }
        public int getDSMark()
        {
            return dsMark;
        }
        public int getDMMark()
        {
            return dmMark;
        }
        public static void addStudent(ArrayList<Student> studentArray)
        {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter Name: ");
            String name = input.next();
            System.out.println("Enter Roll Number");
            int rollNum = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter Web Mark:");
            int webMark = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter Data Structure Mark:");
            int DSMark = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter Discrete Math Mark:");
            int DMMark = input.nextInt();
            //create this student profile in array 
            Student newStudent = new Student(name,rollNum,webMark,DSMark,DMMark);
            studentArray.add(newStudent);
        }
        public static void findStudent(int rollNum, ArrayList<Student> studentArr)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < studentArr.size(); i++)
            {
                if(studentArr.get(i).getRollNum()==rollNum)
                {
                    System.out.println("Roll Number: " + studentArr.get(i).getRollNum() +
                                        ", Name: " + studentArr.get(i).getName() +
                                        ", Web Grade: " + studentArr.get(i).getWebMark() +
                                        ", Data Structure Grade: " + studentArr.get(i).getDSMark() +
                                        ", Discrete Math Grade: " + studentArr.get(i).getDMMark());
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Couldn't find student.");
                }
            }
        }
        public static void deleteStudent(ArrayList<Student> studentArr)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter Student Roll Number: ");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int rollNum = input.nextInt();
            for(int counter = 0; counter < studentArr.size(); counter++)
            {
                if(studentArr.get(counter).getRollNum() == rollNum)
                {
                    studentArr.remove(counter);
                }
            }
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            return name + " " + rollNum + " " + WebMark + " " + dsMark + " " + dmMark;
        }

        public static double avg(ArrayList<Student> studentArr)
        {
            double[] avgArr = new double[studentArr.size()];
            double max = 0.0;
            for(int counter = 0; counter < studentArr.size(); counter++)
            {
                avgArr[counter] = (studentArr.get(counter).getWebMark() + 
                        studentArr.get(counter).getDSMark() + studentArr.get(counter).getDMMark())/(3);

                if(avgArr[counter] > max)
                {
                    max = avgArr[counter];
                }
            }
            return max;
        }

        public int compareTo(Student studCompare)
        {
            int compareRollNum = ((Student) studCompare).getRollNum();

            //ascending order
            return this.rollNum - compareRollNum;
        }

        /*Comparator for sorting the array by student name*/
        public static Comparator<Student> StuNameComparator = new Comparator<Student>() 
        {
            public int compare(Student s1, Student s2) 
            {
               String StudentName1 = s1.getName().toUpperCase();
               String StudentName2 = s2.getName().toUpperCase();

               //ascending order
               return StudentName1.compareTo(StudentName2);

               //descending order
               //return StudentName2.compareTo(StudentName1);
            }
        };

        /*Comparator for sorting the array by student name*/
        public static Comparator<Student> StuRollno = new Comparator<Student>() 
        {
            public int compare(Student s1, Student s2) 
            {
                int rollno1 = s1.getRollNum();
                int rollno2 = s2.getRollNum();

               //ascending order
                return rollno1-rollno2;

               //descending order
               //return StudentName2.compareTo(StudentName1);
            }
        };

        public static <T extends Comparable<T>> List<T> mergeSort(List<T> m)
        {
            // exception
            if (m==null) throw new NoSuchElementException("List is null");
            // base case
            if (m.size() <= 1) return m;

            // make lists
            List<T> left = new ArrayList<>();
            List<T> right = new ArrayList<>();

            // get middle
            int middle = m.size()/2;

            // fill left list
            for (int i = 0; i < middle; i++)
            {
                if (m.get(i)!=null) left.add(m.get(i));
            }

            // fill right list
            for (int i = middle; i < m.size(); i++)
            {
                if (m.get(i)!=null) right.add(m.get(i));
            }

            // recurse
            left = mergeSort(left);
            right = mergeSort(right);

            // merge
            return merge(left,right);
        }

        private static <T extends Comparable<T>> List<T> merge(List<T> left, List<T> right)
        {
            List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();

            // merge
            while (!left.isEmpty() && !right.isEmpty())
            {
                if (left.get(0).compareTo(right.get(0)) <= 0)
                {
                    result.add(left.remove(0));
                }
                else
                {
                    result.add(right.remove(0));
                }
            }

            // cleanup leftovers
            while (!left.isEmpty())
            {
                result.add(left.remove(0));
            }
            while (!right.isEmpty())
            {
                result.add(right.remove(0));
            }
            return result;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userChoice = 0;
        int userChoice2 = 0;
        ArrayList<Student> studentArr = new ArrayList<Student>(); //array size is 6

        System.out.println("1- Merge Sort");
        System.out.println("2- Shell Sort");
        System.out.println("3- Quit");
        userChoice2 = input.nextInt();

        if (userChoice2 == 1 || userChoice2 == 2) 
        {
            do {
                System.out.println("1- Add a New Record");
                System.out.println("2- Sort by Student Name");
                System.out.println("3- Sort by Roll Number");
                System.out.println("4- Delete a Student Specific Record");
                System.out.println("5- Display a Student Specific Record");
                System.out.println("6- Search");
                System.out.println("7- Display the Highest Average");
                System.out.println("8- Print"); //print the array size, sort time, and number of comparisons to the screen.
                System.out.println("9- Quit");
                System.out.println("Select your Option: \n");

                userChoice = input.nextInt();

                switch (userChoice) {
                case 1:
                    Student.addStudent(studentArr);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (userChoice2 == 1) {
                        //call mergesort function
                    } else if (userChoice2 == 2) {
                        //call shell sort function
                    }
                case 3:
                    if (userChoice2 == 1) {
                        //call mergesort function
                    } else if (userChoice2 == 2) {
                        //call shell sort function
                    }
                case 4:
                    Student.deleteStudent(studentArr);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Enter Student Roll Number: ");
                    int rollNum_ = input.nextInt();
                    Student.findStudent(rollNum_, studentArr);
                    break;
                case 6:
                case 7:
                    double highestAvg = Student.avg(studentArr);
                    System.out.println("Highest Average is: " + highestAvg);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    System.out.println("Printing students...");
                    System.out.print(studentArr);
                    System.out.println("\n");
                    break;
                case 9:
                }
            } while (userChoice != 9);
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Student` is already `Comparable` and it **already** compares to other `Student` instances using `rollNum` field, so the current implementation using `compareTo()` should already sort on that field.

But if you want to sort using a different ordering, you could write a `Comparator` and change your sorting method like so:

```
private static <T> List<T> merge(List<T> left, List<T> right, Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
    .. use comparator.compare(a, b) instead of a.compareTo(b)
}
```

Here, you don't need to restrict `T` with `Comparable`.

Comment: By different ordering, do you mean sorting using merge sort? That's what I want to do in this case.

Comment: By different ordering, I mean sorting on a different criteria: for example, using ordering by student's name, mark of something else. I didn't mean a 'different sorting algorithm'.

Comment: How would I implement merge sort in this scenario? using rollNum field.

Comment: Your `Student` class already implements `Comparable` interface, so it has a 'natural ordering'. In this case, you can use `Comparator.naturalOrder()`, if you are on Java 8 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

in order to sort anything , the object must be comparable by somewhat. In java, there are 2 ways to do it for objects (like student):
Comparable and Comparator.

That being said, your object must implement Comparable interface and then write implementation of the necessary method compareTo where you list how you want then to compare to each other.

Another way is to implement Comparator interface and write implementation for compare method.

Once that is done, you can sort the collection with Collection.sort ..... method.

Comment: Hi Zeimer, I want to sort the collection with merge sort. Is that possible?